# internet works fine for few minutes but stop after a minute

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, kubuntu, internet

I just installed Kubuntu on y HP pavillon 15-p088ca and everything was all right since my Internet stopped responding. I tried to ping localhost : everyting was fine, try ping google.com : nothing... The only solution I found is to turn off/on wifi but it still stop after few minutes...

Here is my network configuration :

eti@eti-kubuntu:~$  sudo lshw -class network

*- Wireless card

```
description: Wireless interface

product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter 

vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 

physical id: 0 

bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0 

logical name: wlo1 

version: 00 

serial: 9c:ad:97:93:4f:5b 

width: 64 bits 

clock: 33MHz 

capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet    physical wireless 

configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be   driverversion=4.2.0-25-generic firmware=N/A ip=135.135.21.109   latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn 

resources: irq:42 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fe900000-fe903fff
```

*- ethernet card

```
description: Ethernet interface 

product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet     Controller 

vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 

physical id: 0 

bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0 

logical name: eno1 

version: 07 

serial: 6c:c2:17:72:59:43 

size: 10Mbit/s 

capacity: 100Mbit/s 

width: 64 bits 

Clock: 33MHz 

capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom    ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd a  utonegotiation

configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169    driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1  06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s

resources: irq:36 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fe814000-fe814fff memory:fe810000-fe813fff memory:fe800000-fe80ffff
```

I checked for the kernel version :

eti@eti-kubuntu:~$ uname -nr

eti-kubuntu 4.2.0-25-generic

but according to this site my kernel version support my network card driver : 
https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/rtl819x

Could you help me please??

Thank you :)